# .NET String.Replace Regex Loop 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

So I have code that has been running fine for a while. However, it started throwing `'System.OutOfMemoryException'` exception. The one that fails passes in text that contains about 15-20 links. The error occurs specifically at at `System.String.ReplaceInternal(String oldValue, String newValue)`

So I know the problem , I just don't understand why. The Text being passed in does contains 15 hyperlinks, but the text is less than 1000 characters.

```
Public Shared Function MakeLinksInsideText(pText As String) As String

    'regex for hyperlinks
    Dim regxLinks As New Regex("http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim mactchLinks As MatchCollection = regxLinks.Matches(pText)
    Dim strNewText As String = pText

    'loop through all found hyperlinks and replace the URL with a a tag
    For Each matchLink As Match In mactchLinks
        strNewText = strNewText.Replace(matchLink.Value, "<a target='_blank' class='link_orange' href='" & matchLink.Value & "'>" & matchLink.Value & "</a>")
    Next

    Return strNewText

End Function
```

Comment: Figured it out. The hyperlink was the same link over and over. So the replace function was trying to replace that hyperlink every time in the loop 15 times over.

Comment: Yeah, such loops can be troublesome. I started participating on Stack Overflow last month when I was getting a `StackOverflowException`. I had a method called `GetAllResults()` that looped a bunch of times calling `GetResults()` until nothing was returned. Trouble was I was calling `GetAllResults()` repeatedly and each look at the code seemed fine because of the subtle difference.

Comment: You can add your answer and mark it as correct so others who come across the same problem know what the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The hyperlink was the same link over and over. So the replace function was trying to replace that hyperlink every time in the loop 15 times over.